# Coldfusion installer succeeds, but with no /bin/ directory

Tags: linux, redhat, coldfusion

I've just tried reinstalling a CF9 server, but the installer finishes with "11 NonFatalErrors", and there is no `/cf-root/bin` directory.

This means I can't run `/cf-root/bin/coldfusion start` so I can't run the server. I've tried installing it twice and had no luck.

I installed as *root* from `/opt/`, to `/opt/coldfusion9`, using the `ColdFusion_9_WWE_linux64.bin` file downloaded from Adobe today, and with permissions set to 777 on the file.

The `/cf-root/coldfusion9` folder is missing other directories as well, for example there is no `logs` directory. There also seems to be `coldfusion` and `cfinfo` files in the cf-root folder, these look like they should be in the `bin` folder.

So I have the following:

```
/cf-root/coldfusion9/coldfusion
/cf-root/coldfusion9/cfinfo
/cf-root/coldfusion9/cfstat
```

Instead of

```
/cf-root/coldfusion9/bin/coldfusion
/cf-root/coldfusion9/bin/cfinfo
/cf-root/coldfusion9/bin/cfstat
```

I'm sure I need to post more data here if anyone's going to help but I'm not sure where to look next.

I'm running *Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga)*

Comment: You need at least to provide the error messages and command used to install it.

Comment: The *Adobe_Coldfusion_9_InstallLog.log* file just says "Installation: Successfulwith errors...11 NonFatalErrors" at the end, I don't know where to get more details on the errors

Comment: I've got around my proble, I'll answer it later, I have to wait 8 hours at the moment. Solution is also on Adobe Forums: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1006488